# Generate rectangular with gradient CSS

Tags: css, gradient

How can generate rectangular using gradient in CSS?

[My expectation is like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXWp5.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score -2):

you can try this code to make rectangle by making a div and class as rectangle,

```
.rectangle {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, rgb(84, 255, 84), #329600, rgb(124, 124, 124));
  }
```

you can change the direction of color also.

Comment: You can see in my picture, the left side and top side have the same color, the same as the right side and bottom side.

Comment: you want exact color ?

Comment: No, @ShaikSubhan, I mean the right and bottom sides have the same color but your code is not.

Answer (score -2):

I guess that what you are looking for is a linear gradient. I recomand you to try this web site : https://cssgradient.io/ to easly visualize the render of the css property

> background: linear-gradient

I tried to reproduce what was on your exemple and I get this css code

```css
.exemple{
  width:200px;
  height: 150px;

background: rgb(40,83,62);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(150deg, rgba(40,83,62,1) 5%, rgba(156,200,151,1) 80%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(150deg, rgba(40,83,62,1) 5%, rgba(156,200,151,1) 80%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(150deg, rgba(40,83,62,1) 5%, rgba(156,200,151,1) 80%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#28533e",endColorstr="#ffffff",GradientType=1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Page Title</title>
<body>
  <div class="exemple"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Thanks, @MaximeV but can you add a white diagonal line from top left to bottom right?

Comment: Well that's harder but maybe what you are truely looking for is 

background:conic-gradient

check this out on this web-site : https://angrytools.com/gradient/